# SUBSTITUTE Exact Match in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use the SUBSTITUTE function in Excel to replace an exact match but I'm having no luck. 
For example, cell value = "RD;#4;#RJ;#8;#RY;#10" 
The above value is broken down as follows: [VALUEWANTED;#4] represents total value; ";#" represents a separator between values; [VALUEWANTED;#4];#[VALUEWANTED;#8], etc
I tried SUBSTITUTING, =SUBSTITUTE(I37,";#",","), which reduced some of it to, RD,4,RJ,8,RY,10. Now I need to remove the comma number comma (,number,) between each value. Trying to get it to: RD,RJ,RY

Comment: Text to Columns using semicolon `;` as delimiter, then concat desired results using RIGHT?

Comment: all cells are in the exact format as "RD;#4;#RJ;#8;#RY;#10"    ? are the lengths same too?

Comment: Gowtham, Yes, I'm pulling the data from a SharePoint list and those values are lookup column values, which is why its pulling in ;# and number

Comment: tigeravatar, not sure what you mean. will that separate data from one column into multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(I37,";#",REPT(" ",100)),100,100,""),200,100,""),300,100,""))," ",",")
```

[image]